# Preposition at: This invoice was issued at March 21, 2018

Tags: prepositions

> This invoice was issued at March 21, 2018

Does the previous sentence make any sense?

I am trying to differentiated three information about invoices:

- `issued at`: When the invoice was issued (The legal date that must be
  provided in a printed invoice).
- `registered at`: When the invoice was
  registered in a given software.
- `updated at`: When the invoice was
  updated in a given software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with time, *at* refers to a time of day, while *on* refers to a specific date.

So, you could say:

> This invoice was issued **at** 12:34 PM.

but you would say:

> This invoice was issued **on** March 21, 2018

You could use both prepositions if you were providing a time and a date:

> This invoice was issued **on** March 21, 2018 **at** 12:34 PM.
>   This invoice was issued **at** 12:34 PM **on** March 21, 2018.

Macmillan says:

> **[at](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/at)** (*prep.*) used for stating the exact time when something happens
>   *The game starts at 3 o’clock*
>
> **[on](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on)** (*prep.*) used for saying the day or date when something happens
>   *My birthday is on the 27th of November*

Comment: I must admit I'm surprised this *exact* question doesn't seem to have come up on ELL before. I think Americans are more likely to say ***on** the weekend* where Brits would use ***at*** or ***over***, but apart from that most Anglophones seem remarkably consistent about how we use several different prepositions in date/time contexts *(in Spring, in March, in the afternoon, on Monday, on the twelfth, at 3 o'clock, at night)*. But I don't think I've ever seen any coherent explanation as to *why* we have so many alternatives used so consistently. Any ideas?